# After calling URL "/article/1234abcd" how to retrieve the value `1234abcd` from inside the `article` action?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-parameters, controller-action

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/article", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String article(final ModelMap model)
{
}
```

If this is called using the address:

```
/article/1234abcd
```

How can the value `1234abcd` be retrieved from inside the `article` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `@PathVariable`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/article/{articleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String article(final ModelMap model, @PathVariable String articleId)
{
}
```

See [Spring docs for more info](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates).